# Speed up a select in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a table that has values like these :

Table 1 :

```
 Name   |     DateTimeFrom    |   DateTimeTo
  A     |   2017-02-03 02:00  |  2017-02-10 23:55
  B     |   2017-01-03 14:00  |  2017-05-10 19:55
```

And another table that has values like these :

Table 2:

```
Name |    Date    |  Hour   | Value
  A  | 2017-01-01 |  00:00  |  0.25
  A  | 2017-01-01 |  00:15  |  0.25
  A  | 2017-01-01 |  00:30  |  0
  A  | 2017-01-01 |  00:45  |  0
  A  | 2017-01-01 |  01:00  |  0.25
```

[...] Contains values 0 or 0.25 every 15mins

Result :

```
 Name   |     DateTimeFrom    |   DateTimeTo       | Value
  A     |   2017-02-03 02:00  |  2017-02-10 23:55  |  345.0
  B     |   2017-01-03 14:00  |  2017-05-10 19:55  |  1202
```

I've created a view that contains all the columns from table 1 and the SUM of all the values from the table 2 according to the daterange on the table 1. The problem is that Table 2 contains more than 3 million rows and the SELECT  takes about 10 mins...

Is there a way to speed up the process ?
I tried to create an index on the table 2 but I don't know which index (clustered ? on which columns ? ) i must create to lower the execution time.

Edit (here is the query) :

```
  SELECT Name, DateTimeFrom, DateTimeTo FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name AND Table1.DateTimeFrom <= 
CAST(Table2.Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Table2.Hour AS DATETIME) 
  AND (CASE WHEN Table1.DateTimeTo IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE 
Table1.DateTimeTo END) > CAST(Table2.Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Table2.Hour AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: add the script of your view

Comment: Post your query so someone can help you.  How can we know what's wrong with your query if you don't post it????

Comment: Can you include the sql?  Have you looked at your execution plan?  Table 2 as shown probably does not have a good candidate for a clustered index.  Read this brief overview:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457(v=sql.110).aspx  From what is here without the query you'll either need a covering index for your date field and value field or one on the datefield with an includes for the value column at the very least

Comment: Add your query too, it will be easier to advise you on indexes if the query was posted.

Comment: If you're combining `date` and `hour` from table2 to see if it's between table1 `DateTimeFrom` and `DateTimeTo` then an index might not help much.. If you can combine the `date` and `hour` into a single datetime column and index that you'd be a lot better off.. Maybe even a computed datetime column on table2 if you need to separate date and hour

Comment: Just included the SQL, i thought it was trivial so i didnt include it in the first place... If i combine the Date and the Hour in Table2 would it be faster ?
Actually, i can modify table2 structure, so i'm going to try that..

Answer (score -3):

**Op(Swapper) - Are you trying to only return the past 2 days?**

Start with a non clustered index on table 2 `date` include `value` column.

Then add a filter for only the data set you need, no one can consume 3 million records. something like `where datetimefrom > datediff(month, 1, sysdatetime())` (in the view definition)

A second thought, why compute this data over and over again via a view, consider materializing this data into a table.

Comment: He is not producing 3 million rows. It's an aggregation. The sample result set is just two rows and that's consumable by humans.

Comment: I get that, for all intents and purposes it might as well be 3m records, from the Ops example there are 5 records, 3m/5 per day 600k, or 3m/10 per day 300k - humans can't process that. It might as well be 3m. If it were just two records to return, there would be no question.

Comment: How can you possibly advise about indexes without looking at the workload/query ???? unless you have a crystal ball or something :)